# Regex more lazy than

Tags: regex, lazy-evaluation

I have the following Regex:

```
(?<day>\d+). Tag, (?<way>.+)?( \((?<length>\d+?.?\d?)km\))?
```

And i want to match these three possibilities:

```
1. Tag, Berlin -> London (500.3km)
2. Tag, London -> Stockholm (183km)
3. Tag, Stockholm (day of rest)
```

The problem: It doesn't match the length anymore. If I remove the questionsmarks to this:

```
(?<day>\d+). Tag, (?<way>.+)( \((?<length>\d+?.?\d?)km\))
```

It matches the first and second one not the third one. I thought I could solve the problem by adding the question mark at the end. But then the last expression becomes lazy. So I add another question mark to the `way-`expression but it doesn't become more lazy than the last one. So the way is matching the whole length too!

So, is it possible to define different level of lazyness? And if there this doesn't exist, how should i change the pattern to match it right?

Julian

Comment: You can't match `(day of rest)` with `(\d+?.?)km`. What is the expected output?

Comment: I think the problem is that the `.+` in <way> can match the open bracket character `(`. Maybe use `[^\(]` instead?

Comment: @stribizhev: thats right, because it should not match "(day of rest)". If there is a kilometer-expression the length should match it. If there is no kilometer-expression the "way" will match it. And thats the point, the way is always matching everything including the kilometers.

Comment: I see, so [`(?<day>\d+)\.\s+Tag,\s+(?<way>.+?)\s+\((?<length>[^()]+)\)`](https://regex101.com/r/jN1bZ2/1) is not a solution, right? What is the regex flavor, BTW?

Comment: @pzelasko: Unfortunately "(day of rest)" should getting matched by the way-expression. So if i forbid the bracket, the day of rest won't get matched.

Comment: The "(day of rest)" should be in way and not in the length :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to match all the expected elements in your input:

```
(?<day>\d+)\.\s+Tag,\s+(?<way>(?:[^()]|\((?!\d+(?:\.\d+)?km)[^()]*\))*?)(?:$|\s*(?<length>\(\d+(?:\.\d+)?km\)))
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/jN1bZ2/4)

You can match the whole `way` that consists of no parenthetical constructs or with them not having integer or float numbers with `km` right after. Length will be matched only if present. Also note that a literal dot must be escaped (`\.`).

Comment: Hm... nearly. Now the kilometers are also in the way-expression :/ the way only should match "Berlin -> London" without the (500.3km)

Comment: Well, I have re-vamped the expression a bit, does it work as expected now?

Comment: 1. Tag, Berlin -> London (500.3km)

    day: 1
    way: Berlin -> London
    length: 500.3

2. Tag, London -> Stockholm (183km)

    day: 2
    way: London -> Stockholm
    length: 183

3. Tag, Stockholm (day of rest)

    day: 3
    way: Stockholm (day of rest)
    length:

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, works fine :) Now you have done, seems so easy -.-